# deciding language and server for the online back-end system

Tags: java, tomcat, ssh, administration, web-development-server

I need to make an **on-line system/webapp/server** that connects to an **mySQL Server**. this web app/server must accept incoming communications from an **android app** and then make changes to the database. Also there needs to be an **"Web Admin Console"** to do manual data manipulation.

I was considering using **Java with Tomcat** for the web application the system needs to run on:

- open source frameworks
- be well documented technology
- secure data transmission

are there any other software/languages i could use? how do i set up the web console? there needs to be an SSH access as well...

How do I start with making this online system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can develop complete system in JEE6.  You can choose RESTful WebServices for integrating Android Application and Web Application too.  For developing web application you can go with JSF if you want rich look and feel.  Else you can stick with normal JSP and frameworks like jQuery and Twitter Bootstrap etc.

Comment: how about Apache HTTP server with PHP? intead of tomcat with jsp?

Comment: well it is all depending on the skillset you have.  Technically PHP is also excellent technology for developing web applications. But each technology has their own merits and demerits.